# Javascript to read file names under a directory

Tags: javascript, xml

I have placed some XML files under a directory. I need to populate a drop down using javascript to display all those XML file names. How do I do that?

Comment: Need to use a server-side language to read files, then use AJAX to hand it off to JavaScript. (Best guess given no other information).

Comment: Is this a local directory on the client's machine, or on the server? JavaScript can't access either local or remote directories due to the huge security concerns.

Comment: @JamWaffles the directory is the server.

Comment: @Brad Christie How do i do that? If u can provide more info it would be appreciable.

Comment: Whats the server side language you are using?

Comment: @Fawzanmohammed: There are still more questions: What language are you already using or have access to? (PHP, ASP, ...?) Is the page you're hoping to populate hosted on the same server as the files?

Comment: @Fawzanmohammed I created a code sample in my answer with ajax

Comment: @BradChristie im using PHP.. yep.. itz on the same server..

Answer (score 1):

You've been way too broad when it comes to circumstances and situation, so I'll be broad back with an answer.

Given the following:

- The web-page with the `<select>` you need to populate is hosted on the same server as the file list.
- The server has the ability to use a server-side language (e.g. PHP, ASP)
- You don't mind, or can at least decipher jQuery code (makes what I'm about to post more about the concept than the practice)

You will need something like the following setup:

**Create a server-side file that dumps a list of file names**

You're going to need to look up some way to retrieve and dump the list of the files. This is so JavaScript & AJAX can go fetch this list and dump in in to the drop-down list. Example output of said script (which I'm aliasing as `/server-side-file-list` in the JavaScript below)

```
file-001.xml
file-002.xml
file-003.xml
file-004.xml
```

**Setup the `<select>` on your page**

```
<!-- Somewhere in the page -->
<select id="xml-file-list" name="xml-file-list"></select>
```

**Setup the JavaScript/Ajax code**

```
<!-- This should go in the <head></head> portion of your page with the select -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/server-side-file-list',
      success: function(d){
        $.each(d.split(/[\r\n]+/),function(i,e){
          $('<option />',{ value: e }).text(e).appendTo('#xml-file-list');
        });
      }
  });
</script>
```

---

Basic work-flow:

1. HTML page loads up with an empty `<select>`
2. jQuery takes over and fetches a list of files from that `/server-side-file-list` script using AJAX (behind the scenes)
3. The results are returned and placed in to the `<select>` as `<option>`s.
4. Done.

--

### Food for thought:

A better method may be to load your file list in to the page at run time (if possible). That is to say, if the page you're working on is an ASP or PHP or other type of server-side language page, you can retrieve the file list when the page is called upon and load it at that time (and avoid using javascript altogether).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about *local* files, you need a browser that supports the [W3C FileSystem API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/).

You can test for compatibility at www.html5test.com

Answer (score 0):

If you're completely agnostic about the name of xml file you will need a server-side language to get a list of file of a server directory.

Otherwise, if you're in control of filenames, a workaround could be give them a progressive name (e.g. `1.xml`, `2.xml`...) and try to make some chained ajax `HEAD` calls.

If the ajax request of 1.xml returns a `200` server status, then ask for 2.xml and so on, until you get a 404 error. For each ajax call you can add the name to an array and then use it to create a dynamic `select`.

Of course, for a matter of performance, this should be intended only as a **workaround** and it's **not** reliable at all, since a 404 could occur even if the resource exists, so I strongly suggest to use a server side language

anyway this is a jQuery 1.5+ example explaining the workaround. Suppose you have `1.xml, 2.xml` and `3.xml`. The HTML is just an empty select

```
<select id="xmlfiles"></select>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    /**
     * we need to only know if the resource exists or not
     */
    $.ajaxSetup({ type : "head" });


    /**
     * Function reading xml file. When deferred has been resolved 
     * (when first 404 occurs) an array of filename is passed.
     */
    function getXMLFile(path) {

        var deferred  = $.Deferred(),
            xmlFiles  = [];

        (function getFile( i ) {
            var url = [path, i, '.xml'].join('');
            $.when($.ajax(url))
            .done(function() {
                xmlFiles.push(url);
                getFile( ++i );
            })
            .fail(function() {
                deferred.resolve(xmlFiles);
            });
        }(1));

        return deferred.promise();    
    };


    /**
     * when we have read xmlfiles in "./" then for each file 
     * retrieved append an option
     */
    $.when(getXMLFile('./')).then(function(file) {
        var select = $('#xmlfiles');
        /* create options */

        $.each(file, function(i, filename) {
            var option = $('<option></option>');
            option.html(filename).attr('value', filename).appendTo(select)
        })
    });

});
</script>
```

and this shows a select with options

./1.xml
./2.xml
./3.xml

(Sorry for my verbosity)